# Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9, swift4

However I have recompiled the framework using the same Xcode and it still gives me this error.

- Base SDK iOS 11.1 for both
- Swift Language Version Swift 4.0 for both
- Not using Pods/Carthage

I hope someone might know

Comment: It seems that Apple needs to reconsider that 10 year deprecation notice for Objective C :^) This has bitten me on >1 project now and on both these are 3rdparty binary frameworks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60911546/4427884

Answer (score 142, accepted):

**Update:**

*For release versions of Xcode:*

This error (and similar errors involving Swift 4.1, 4.2, etc.) will occur when opening a project with Xcode 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 10, etc. that uses frameworks that were built with earlier Xcode tools.

To fix the issue, update and rebuild your frameworks using Carthage ( `carthage update --platform iOS`), Cocoapods (`pod update` or `pod install`), or manually, with the new updated Xcode tools. The tools should be updated automatically when you update Xcode, but if not, you can follow the steps outlined below in the original answer.

You may also need to clean your project `cmd + shift + k` and possibly your build folder `cmd + option + shift + k` to get Xcode to not use cached framework builds.

In some cases you may also need to delete your derived data folder (Easily found by going to Xcode Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data Folder 
 ([Thanks Stunner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47051670/347339))

*For beta versions of Xcode:*

See original answer below and then follow steps above.

**Original Answer:**

You probably still have your xcodebuild tools set to Xcode 9.0 which builds with Swift 4.0 and is incompatible with Xcode 9.1 beta's Swift 4.0.1.

Check in the terminal using the command:

```
xcodebuild -version
```

Or just go into Xcode preferences -> Locations and check/change the command line tools to Xcode 9.1. You should be set then.

Comment: I also cleared Derived data, and cleaned the project, don't know if necessary for everyone but here it seemed to be. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Zig. A repo I use on github (mattdonnelly/swifter) is at Swift 4.0, but has obviously been compiled using XCode 9.0, so I'm getting this problem. What are the steps needed to recompile someone's else cocoapod on Github for XCode 9.1 and above?

Comment: is there a way to add command line tool? I just have Xcode 9.3 in my command line dropdown. and I have this problem too

Comment: Some of my pods aren't ready for Swift 4.2, hence I had to pin the `Swift Language Version` to `Swift 4` for those. Then it worked.

Comment: Plus 1 for the shortcut for cleaning the build folder--wasn't something I knew how to do offhand.

Comment: I'm having this issue after upgrading to Xcode 10.2 (which introduces Swift 5). My build settings still say "Swift 4.2" and I rebuilt all my Carthage/Cocoapods dependencies, but the issue persists...

Comment: Worked for me with Xcode 11  with error (swift 5) and swift 5.1

Comment: After updating Xcode to 12.5 I got the error in my Swift 5 project for a Swift 4 libary (Cocoapods) that's been working fine. There's no update for it, so I just cleaned the project and now the error's gone again.

Answer (score 27):

My issue was due to an external framework not being compiled for Swift 4.0.2. I had added this file via [Carthage](https://www.raywenderlich.com/165660/carthage-tutorial-getting-started-2), so running:

```
carthage update --platform iOS
```

And then cleaning the project `cmd + shift + k` and build folder `cmd + option + shift + k` and deleting the derived data folder (merely moving it to trash works as well) worked for me.

Comment: indeed, this is essentially the solution.  The same thing just happened today (April 18), due to Apple's latest swift update!  :)

Comment: cmd + option + shift + k is what did the trick after updating Carthage. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I downloaded xCode 11 Beta version to test SwiftUI. When i run my project, i got **"Module compiled with Swift 5.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0.1 compiler:..."** error.

To do fix this issue. i changed xCode command line tool to new xCode 11 comment line tool. After that, you can create new xcode project with SwiftUI.

**Xcode -> Preferences -> Location -> XCode command Line Tool**

[image: Xcode Commend Line Tool]

i hope, this will help someone who want to test with new freamework :)

Answer (score 9):

Install Xcode Toolchain of specific Xcode version which was working for you from [here](https://swift.org/download/#releases).

An Xcode toolchain includes a copy of the compiler, lldb, and other related tools needed to provide a cohesive development experience for working in a specific version of Swift.

Open Xcode's Preferences, navigate to Components > Toolchains , and select the installed Swift toolchain.

This will let you compile and run the app for now.

Comment: After 2 days of searching and trying every possible solution with carthage update, bootstrap, swift language settings etc. I found the right answer here :)

Answer (score 7):

I hit this issue with Xcode 10 beta, which adds Swift 4.2. My issue was unrelated to Carthage or any external dependencies.

Go to `YourTarget > Build Settings > Swift Language Version` for all of your Xcode targets.

Mine were all set to `Swift 4`.

After adding a Copy Files Build Phase, I started getting the error

> :0: error: module compiled with Swift 4.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2 compiler: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-faskfrihumfcdibjxisjvbfshppp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/Debug/MyAppExtension.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyClass~partial.swiftmodule
>
> Command MergeSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code

I then set each target's `Swift Language Version` to `Swift 4.2`, which eliminated the error.

I'm not sure why the error was occuring in the first place, though, as having all targets set to `Swift 4` should be equally as valid.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding `Build Settings`

Comment: @Chandrew click on your Target first. Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

In my case (Xcode 9.2):

I went to Xcode `Preferences > Locations > Derived Data`

I then deleted the data and did a clean build and was ok.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used CocoaPods with plugin `cocoapods-binary` to prebuild libraries to binaries. After I upgrade Xcode from 10 to 11, Xcode gives me this error:

```
Module compiled with Swift 5.0.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1 compiler
```

I fix it by removing the `/Pods` directory and running `pod install`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I re-compiled the framework with whatever version it was complaining about.

To recompile, run `pod update` or update the carthage (which ever one you're using), and build the project.

Then search for the framework in finder. Copy-paste the `theFramework.framework` to your project and make sure to "Copy items if needed."Build the project again and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with a few basic steps

- `Close Xcode`
- `pod deintegrate`
- `Open Xcode workspace`
- `Command + Shift + K` - Clean
- `Command + B` - Build