# How does one rebuild a cocoapod (hosted at github) without making any edits?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

The context is specifically that I am facing the problem described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726077/module-compiled-with-swift-4-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-4-0-1) which is due to a [Cocoapod hosted on github](https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter) that has been updated to Swift 4.0 and built in XCode 9.0. XCode is now at version 9.2 and uses Swift 4.0.3, and when this module is imported it displays the following compile-time error:

```
Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.3
```

The code does not need changing, the pod simply needs rebuilding in XCode 9.2.

How can this be achieved, please?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: How did you solve this issue? getting "Module compiled with Swift 4.0.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2 compiler"