# how to install Almofire without CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

i am using Almofire without using CocoaPods in my project. When i add the Framework and import the Almofire will occur and it show me the error below

> Module compiled with Swift 4.0.3 cannot be imported in Swift 4.1:
>   /Users/task/Documents/IOS
>   Apps/appName/Alamofire.framework/Modules/Alamofire.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule.

Comment: possible duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726077/module-compiled-with-swift-4-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-4-0-1?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: i already try that but its not working my Xcode version is 9.3 and swift is 4.1

Comment: why you not using it as pod file?

Comment: I think if you add pod file in your project and install Almofire as a pod file your issue will be fixed, give it a try , make a new copy of your project and add pods to it, if it work, do it on your original project.

Comment: it occurs error when building a file

Comment: You should check that your using the latest Almofire framework, for that it will be more easier if you use it as a pod, you only need to update the pod file, i sagest as edit to you question please accept it .

Comment: please sent me the link of latest Almofire framework

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire