# Module compiled with Swift 4.0.3 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2 compiler

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode10, carthage

One of our developer built an iOS app using Xcode.

I'm trying to run archive an iOS app. But I'm getting error

> Module compiled with Swift 4.0.3 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2 compiler

I'm using Xcode 10, Carthage and Pods.

Swift language version is 4.0

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Edit 1: I tried to update Carthage, I got the following error "Task failed with exit code 65: This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile."

Comment: your application built using Swift 4.0.3 now you are compling it on 4.2 or 4.0 , check the module that giving this error or run on 4.0.3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726077/module-compiled-with-swift-4-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-4-0-1

Comment: I think there is any framework or any module that is built with the 4.0.3 and you are trying to compile it using 4.2 so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726077/module-compiled-with-swift-4-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-4-0-1)

Comment: Which is the module that is giving the error? I had the same issue because a dependency I was using in CocoaPods. I just had to run pod update to update that dependency to the latest available. Regards.

Comment: After trying from the link above, I got the following error: " I tried to update Carthage, I got the following error "Task failed with exit code 65: This usually indicates that project itself failed to compile.""