# Old framework version incompatible with iOS 13, new framework incompatible with iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, backwards-compatibility

I have developed a swift iOS app that uses frameworks Moya and Alamofire.

In preparation for iOS 13, I've downloaded Xcode 11 with Swift 5.1 and when I loaded my projects, Moya framework reported error “Module compiled with Swift 5.0 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1 compile”.

I’ve tried to troubleshoot using this solution [Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726077/module-compiled-with-swift-4-0-cannot-be-imported-in-swift-4-0-1) however, that didn't help so I installed pre-release versions of the frameworks.

However, the app can't be run on iOS 12 now because the pre-release version of Moya (maybe its Alamofire which Moya is dependent on) uses Apple's Combine framework.

Is there any other solution to this or will I have to satisfy myself with this app running only on iOS 13?

Comment: Try to add those module files directly into the project as third party, instead of pods. Remember to remove the imports like `import Alamofire`.

Answer (score 0):

Use "clean" + "remove derived data"; select proper "command line tools" in the preferences. Rebuild again