# Module compiled with Swift 5.0.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I can not solve this issue, please help!

https://prnt.sc/pmvltr

Comment: This question is a duplicate. There's a ton of good advice on this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46726077/814416

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `Swift Language Version` to `Swift 5` in

> **`Target`** (**Aviasales Kit**) > **Build Settings** > **Swift Compiler - Language** > **Swift Language Version**

Comment: Thanks, but it's not help.. Do you know other method ??

Comment: Or try another lower version of swift which supports both of your version issue. e.g. Swift 4 or 4.2